# Error: No component factory found for [Component Name]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading, angular8

I am trying to make a stackblitz but I am getting below error when I try to run it:

```
Error: No component factory found for TasksComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

Here is the url reference: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jtpuch)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means that your component `TasksComponent` cannot be created. You need to add it to `entryComponents`. Read https://angular.io/guide/entry-components

Comment: @akash I have already did that. Can you please refere my stackblitz?

Comment: @akash https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jtpuch

Comment: @akash when I add in `entryComponents` I am getting this error: `TasksComponent cannot be used as an entry component.`

Comment: Move  task component decorator above export class TasksComponent and make sure to include Taskcomponent inside TasksModule decalaration

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fs2hws?file=src/app/tasks/tasks.module.ts

Comment: entryComponents are no longer needed since angular 10.

Comment: @ThorstenRintelen I am using angular 8

Answer (score 0):

Please put the Annotation

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tasks',
    templateUrl: './tasks.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tasks.component.css']
})
```

directly over the class:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tasks',
    templateUrl: './tasks.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tasks.component.css']
})
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {
```

Comment: what is this? I didn't get this